# Twitter4j getting tweets outside of the bounding box

Tags: java, geolocation, maps, twitter4j, bounding-box

```
                FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
                double lat = 41.0136;
                double longitude = 28.9744;
                double lat1 = lat - .50;
                double longitude1 = longitude - .50;
                double lat2 = lat + .50;
                double longitude2 = longitude + .50;

                double[][] bb= {{longitude1,lat1}, {longitude2,lat2}};
                fq.locations(bb);
                twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

Here is a piece of code that i am using to get tweets with geolocations. I read that many people had problem with latitude,longitude order or with bounding box they are sending to the filter. My coordinates looks correct and i am defining my bounding box from SW corner to NE corner. Still i am getting tweets from all over the country (Turkey) rather than getting tweets from a single city (Istanbul).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that Twitter4j uses the location information *specified in the user's profile* to extract the location information about the user (and consequently their tweets).  This means that the actual coordinates from which someone tweets are not used to determine whether or not that tweet came from within the bounding box.  Therefore, if a person's profile specifies that the user is located within the bounding box, they may show up as having tweeted within the bounding box despite the fact that they aren't physically tweeting from within it.